# Why do I get questionblock after just two deleted questions?

Tags: bug

I would like to know, how the questionblocks come.

I asked on programmers exactly three questions. One I deleted myself, another one was deleted by community and the third got one upvote, two answers and one accepted answer.

But I am again blocked from asking questiions. How does it come?

Comment: Am I the only one who finds it absolutely disgusting that a Q&A site, or what claims to be a Q&A site, would actually have a way to *discourage* people from using it?  Sounds legit crazy to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have asked 5 questions on Programmers:

- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/235271/modify-memory-in-borland-6 asked on April 8, self-deleted on April 8
- [Should I use HTTP search](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/233158/should-i-use-http-search) asked on March 21, open, net score of 1
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/232123/standard-way-for-webrequest asked on March 12, closed by 5 user votes, deleted, net score of -1
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189617/install-cloud9-on-windows-8-or-linux asked on March 7, 2013, closed by 5 user votes, deleted, net score of -4
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/188926/migrate-wcf-to-node-js asked on March 1, 2013, closed with 5 votes, deleted by moderator, net score of -4

Across these questions, your net question score is -8, which isn't that good. The details of the automatic question block algorithm are not known outside of the Stack Exchange team - not even to moderators.

You should read [the page in the help center about question bans](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans) as well as a [a Meta Stack Exchange post that describes the question block and how to get out of it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th). The advice is to fix your old posts (if you can) and contribute good posts of the type that you can (you can still post answers to questions).

Comment: Ok, I just get the first 3 listed in my profile, I am confused a bit. Yeah the last part is no question, I just got confused, that I wasn't able to post a second question after the Borland one, which I actually reasked on stackoverflow after I deleted it by myself.

Comment: @Knerd Because the details of the blocking algorithm aren't known, it's hard to say why it was triggered. Perhaps your self-deletion triggered it. No one here knows, and the people who do won't disclose why. I know that migrations favored over deletion if you ask a question on a wrong site, but it does seem a little odd to me that a self-deletion would trigger the block.

Comment: ok, you helped me thanks :) But it is very anoyning not to know why it is triggered. And as far as I can see, my answers are fairly good and it is kinda weird for me, that answers help to unblock a question ban but that they can't protect of it. Sorry for maybe bad english, I am german and my scottish girlfriend isn't correcting my english atm ^^

Comment: @Knerd The only advice I could give is to consider posting on Meta Stack Overflow since the algorithm is used across the network. Is it weird that a self-deletion triggered it, but without knowing if it's supposed to work that way, I can't be sure.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help :) Then I just gonna answer questions again :)

Comment: The self-deleted question didn't really have any effect here, apart from adding one more question to your account that didn't *improve* your stats @Knerd. The three down-voted, closed then deleted questions are lookin' pretty guilty though.

Comment: @Shog9 Just seems weird that the last deleted post was in March. That means the last down vote was also cast in March. The last open question was asked before the deletion, but the self-deleted post was asked well after the last "bad" action (closure, deletion, or down vote) to any of the other questions. It just seems weird that anyone would have a bunch of closed/deleted/down voted questions, be able to ask two more (including one with an up vote), delete one question, then run into the question ban. But this is your area of expertise to say for sure - just seems odd to me.

Comment: The raw number of questions asked does have an influence here too, @Thomas (I'd have to check the code to see exactly what triggered this, but so far as I can see literally *nothing* happened to that last question apart from it being posted and deleted). Adding preemptive warnings to this system is... on my list.

Comment: Thomas, it seems to be documented that self-deletions contribute to ban: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229372/what-could-have-triggered-a-question-ban-in-this-case#comment753069_229372